# How can I use arr.forEach to call async JavaScript redis calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, redis

I'm working with node.js and redis. I've got a redis database with a bunch of keys. Something like this:

user/chris/potion
user/pete/potion
user/chris/race
user/pete/race
user/chris/weapon
user/pete/weapon

I want to do a redis call which retrieves all user stats, puts the stats into a JS object, then passes it to the client for displaying character stats in the browser. Using javascript I inject the username chris at *u* into the redis call like this:

```
KEYS user/u/*
```

which returns:

```
1) "user/chris/weapon"
2) "user/chris/race"
3) "user/chris/potion"
```

Now I can iterate through those results, get the value of each key with GET, and make a javascript object. Seems super simple so I write the code. I quickly run into problems using forEach:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();

    exports.getUserObject = function(requesteduser, callback) {

        var userstats = {}; // the object to hold the user stats once retrieved from the db
        client.KEYS('user/' + requesteduser + '/*', function(err, replies) {

             replies.forEach(function (reply, i) {
                 client.GET(reply, function(err, value) {
                      // get the key name so we can populate a js object
                      var n = reply.lastIndexOf('/');
                      var key = reply.substring(n + 1, reply.length);
                      userstats[key] = value;

                      console.dir(userstats);

                      callback(null, userstats); // parent expects (err, userstats)
                 });

             });
        });
}
```

When ran, output is like this:

```
{ weapon: 'twosword' }
{ weapon: 'twosword', race: 'elf' }
{ weapon: 'twosword', race: 'elf', potion: 'mana' }
```

`callback(null, userstats)` is called three times. Calling callback more than once will be problematic, since eventually callback will trigger data being sent data to the client.

I think I know what is happening. `client.GET` is ran three times because I asked it to. The `replies` array has three elements, so each time the result comes in for `client.GET`, the callback is called.

What I need to happen is for the forEach loop to finish iterating through all the redis keys, and once that's done, call the callback once. I tried solving this problem first with promises, then with async, because async has async.each. I got stuck solving the problem with both. I'm back to square one now, I'm convinced I have to do something different with forEach to make progress.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Would moving `callback(null, userstats);` outside of the `forEach` not solve the problem?

Comment: @Greg, That was one of the first things I tried but because client.GET(?) is an asynchronous function,the callback gets called before client.GET returns the first value. I end up with an empty userstats object.

Comment: of course! forgot the async ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're iterating over `replies`, you can check when you've reached the last element and only call `callback` in that instance.

```
client.KEYS('user/' + requesteduser + '/*', function(err, replies) {

         replies.forEach(function (reply, i) {
             client.GET(reply, function(err, value) {
                  // get the key name so we can populate a js object
                  var n = reply.lastIndexOf('/');
                  var key = reply.substring(n + 1, reply.length);
                  userstats[key] = value;

                  console.dir(userstats);

                  if (i == replies.length-1) callback(null, userstats); // parent expects (err, userstats)
             });

         });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a little late to help @Grimtech but I'll leave my opinion for other people that arrives here eventually:

First of all I rather to model @Grimtech's problem differently. Something like this:

```
client.hmset("user:chris", "weapon", "some weapon", "race", "some race", "potion", "some potion");
client.hmset("user:pete", "weapon", "same weapon", "race", "other race", "potion", "other potion");
```

Then I would have a method in Node returning a *json* like the following, assuming that I can have more than one key starting with "user:chris":

```
router.get('/users/:user_id', function(req, res, next) {
    var response = [];
    var client = redis.createClient();
    client.keys("user:" + req.params.user_id + "*", function (err, users) {
        users.forEach(function (key, pos) {
            client.hgetall(key, function (err, user) {
                response.push(user);
                if (pos === users.length - 1) {
                    res.json(response);
                    client.quit();
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The *if (pos === users.length - 1)* solves the async issue.

The json returned will have all the "user:chris" attributes so yo can do whatever you want in the client browser.